# Force window relocation through a form - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, xmlhttprequest

I am building a fake login form which should load locally a different url if the user inserts the correct credentials. This is the `html` code:

```
<div class="container">
    <h2>Login page - Welcome</h2>   
    <form id="loginForm" onsubmit="subLogin()">
        Username: <input id="userName" type="text" name="userName" required><br/>
        Password: <input id="passWord" type="password" name="password" required><br/>
        <button type="submit" id="login-button" value="Login">Login</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

And this is the `javascript` where I try to relocate the user via `window.location.href = "/index.html"`.

```
function subLogin() {
    var userName = document.getElementById('userName').value;
    var passWord = document.getElementById('passWord').value;
    if (userName !== 'mickeymouse' || passWord !== 'DisneyLand') {
        alert('Your username or password is not correct');
    } else {
        window.location.href = 'http://localhost:8000/index.html';
    };
};
```

If the username or password are wrong, but if they are correct the `window.location` does not work as espected.

Is there a way to solve this issue with pure `javascript`, or is it better to use anyway a `XMLHttp GET Request` via `ajax`? Thanks in advance for your replies!

Comment: Can't understand , where is your problem. I mean which is not working as expected

Comment: I forgot to insert that part, my bad. I have problems with `window.location`, since if username and password are correctly submitted it doesn't redirect the user to '/index.html'

Comment: redirecting the page is done with (window.location=url)! window.location.href just returns the current url

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp

Comment: I tried also with `window.location`, but it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue. I have simply changed the form to:

```
<form id="loginForm" action="javascript:subLogin()"></form>
```

I post the code in case that someone may need it in the future. Thanks anyway for your replies!